# Best way to avoid complicated if else branching - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I have rest API which uses several parameters ( as requestparams) to search entity. There could be multiple variations of this search. Following methods get calls at the end for searching entity with given parameters.

```
public List<Person> searchPerson(final String name, 
           final String city, final String state, final String code) {
    if( name != null && city != null && state != null && code != null ){
        //Search person in database with above all parameters
        //personRepositoy is spring data repository. 
        personRepositoy.findByNameAndCityAndStateAndCode(name, city, state, code);
    } else if( city != null && state != null && code != null){
        personRepositoy.findByCityAndStateAndCode(name, city, state, code)
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid complicated ( error prone , not so easy to refactor) branching here ? May be using Collections or functional programming concept ? I really not comfortable writing this kind of branching code ( since these are hard to maintain)

Comment: There's little you can do about it: your repository API is too restrictive with its `findByThisAndThat` approach, which is prone to ode duplication. The best approach here would be to convince the writer of the repository API to give you an API that lets you pass `null`s, and do it in their repository code: if they are reading from DB, they have a very easy option to treat conditions with `null`s as non-existent.

Comment: have you ever considered to expose your API as graphql? http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own utility for that something like this:

```
public static boolean requireNonNull(Object... objects) {
    for(Object obj : objects) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example usage

```
public List<Person> searchPerson(final String name, final String city, 
                                 final String state, final String code) {
    if(MyUtilityClass.requireNonNull(name, city, state, code)) {
        //Search person in database with above all parameters
        //personRepositoy is spring data repository. 
        personRepositoy.findByNameAndCityAndStateAndCode(name, city, state, code);
    } else if(MyUtilityClass.requireNonNull(city, state, code)) {
        personRepositoy.findByCityAndStateAndCode(city, state, code)
    }
}
```

Comment: The "core" branching problem stays the same here, only the syntax becomes shorter.

Answer (score 2):

`city != null && state != null && code != null` might be saved in a variable.

```
boolean cityStateCodeGiven = city != null && state != null && code != null;

if(name != null && cityStateCodeGiven) {
    // name, city, state, code are given
} else if (cityStateCodeGiven) {
    // city, state, code are given
}
```

You don't need to recheck some conditions twice or more.

For instance, `cityStateCodeGiven` might be split to `cityStateGiven + codeGiven`. `name != null && cityStateCodeGiven` can be grouped into  `nameCityStateCodeGiven`.

The name of a variable will tell which conditions the variable checks.

---

Moreover, you could put these declarations at the beginning of the method. It will give some hints about the methods you are going to use in the code later.

```
boolean cityStateCodeGiven = city != null && state != null && code != null;
boolean nameCityStateCodeGiven = cityStateCodeGiven && name != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code as the following for clarity

```
if(name!=null)
{
  if(city!=null)
  {
    if(state!=null
    {
      if(code!=null)
      { 
        // do search using all
        }
        //search using name , city , code
        }
         // search using name , city
         } 
         //search using name only
         }
```

Comment: This is worse than the original OP approach, because the number of nested branches is going to explode to cover all possible arrangements.

Comment: I think it's better because you eliminate duplicate null checks. Before this code explodes the `personRepository` will explode with specific `find` methods.

Comment: what if I want to search using name and code? then I would add another if condition in each else block, which would make it even worse. as @dasblinkenlight said. this is worse than the original approach

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to tell without knowing how the different checks interact.

Anyway, the following article gives you 5 different solutions (patterns) to make your if-else conditions more readable: [Anti-If: The missing patterns](https://code.joejag.com/2016/anti-if-the-missing-patterns.html)

Hope that you can use one of them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I offer to look at this problem more wide. I could expect following things:

1. You have already 4 different search properties for search a Person;
2. I could expect that you have more search fields in the future and more different combinations.

Therefore I offer to unit all these fields into special object `SearchPersonRequest`.

Then, you have this object and it could have a special behavior, *like create search request for search engine, i.e. `SpringData`*. When you have multiple filed for searching with multiple combinations, it is much flexible to use `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.

This is my main point. As an example, I give you my first approach of this (you see `Lombok` annotations, it just only for simplify the code; it is not required to use it):

**SearchPersonRequest**

```
@Builder
public class SearchPersonRequest {

    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String code;

    public Specification<Person> createSpecification() {
        List<Specification<Person>> specifications = getSpecifications();
        Specifications<Person> spec = null;

        if (!specifications.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Specification<Person>> it = specifications.iterator();
            spec = where(it.next());

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                spec = spec.and(it.next());
            }
        }

        return spec;
    }

    private List<Specification<Person>> getSpecifications() {
        return Arrays.stream(Field.values())
                     .filter(field -> field.isExists(this))
                     .map(field -> (Specification<Person>)(root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(root.get(field.id), field.get.apply(this)))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private enum Field {
        NAME("name", request -> request.name),
        CITY("city", request -> request.city),
        STATE("state", request -> request.state),
        CODE("code", request -> request.code);

        private final String id;
        private final Function<SearchPersonRequest, String> get;

        private boolean isExists(SearchPersonRequest request) {
            return StringUtils.isNotBlank(get.apply(request));
        }
    }

}
```

**PersonController**

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    public List<Person> searchPerson(@RequestParam String name,
                                     @RequestParam String city,
                                     @RequestParam String state,
                                     @RequestParam String code) {
        SearchPersonRequest searchPersonRequest = SearchPersonRequest.builder()
                                                                     .name(name)
                                                                     .city(city)
                                                                     .state(state)
                                                                     .code(code)
                                                                     .build();
        return searchPerson(searchPersonRequest);
    }

    public List<Person> searchPerson(@RequestBody SearchPersonRequest searchPersonRequest) {
        return personService.searchPerson(searchPersonRequest);
    }

}
```

**PersonService**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public List<Person> searchPerson(SearchPersonRequest searchPersonRequest) {
        Specification<Person> spec = searchPersonRequest.createSpecification();
        return spec != null ? personRepository.findAll(spec) : Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

**PersonRepository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {

}
```

Comment: what if OP doesn't have Spring in his stack?

Comment: No problem, then build SQL with available tools in `SearchPersonRequest`. I just give a common approach without specific details.